# How do I scan a QR code with React App using your phone?

Tags: reactjs

I have an react app and I want to do the following:

1. Click on a button which allows your phone to scan a QR code.
2. Use your phone to scan another QR code.
3. Return the QR code scanned through your phone to the react app.

Are there any packages that help with this?

Comment: Using "your phone". My phone ?

Comment: Yes, from the web app on a PC --> a QR code appears so the user can scan it using their phone ---> after scanned ---> a camera appears and using their phone they will scan another QR code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to install a QR generating library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.

This is a great step by step resource that you can refer to create the QR code and can be found here: https://dev.to/ruppysuppy/add-qr-code-to-react-websites-in-2-minutes-j05 . However since yours is on button click, you can probably move the function body in the guide's useEffect function into the button's onClick function.

A notable function in that library is the toCanvas function that will draw the actual QR code itself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode#tocanvascanvaselement-text-options-cberror

Comment: Actually, I want to generate a "special" link that I can encode as a QR code from the web app, so then a separate physical phone can scan that QR code from web application on the PC and scan another QR code using the webcam of that physical phone

Comment: I see, in that case you will have to download a QR code generator library instead. I have changed the answer to reflect it as such.

Comment: I think the part to convert text to qr code is easy, but need help on the following: 1. After phone scans the qr code from web app on pc ---> web app notices it and shows 'loading' screen, at the same time phone opens the camera so another qr code can be read

Comment: it is like KYC companies do when they want to scan your driver license.

Comment: Hmm I'm thinking in that case you will need the QR code scanned by the phone to trigger an API call to your web app. It will then trigger a change in a state variable, for example ```setLoading=true```. You will need to implement a ```useEffect``` hook for this loading variable to display the loading page.